# Convert last column to categorical if the dataframe don't have columns with name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe without explicitly named columns.

The last column contains strings of 3 variants, so I want to cast them to a categorical datatype. How can I do this?

I'm doing this:

```py
df[df.iloc[:, -1]] = pd.Categorical(df[df.iloc[:, -1]])
```

I'm not sure how to modify a column when it doesn't have a name.

Comment: Can you clarify what your dataframe looks like

Answer (score 1):

One can simply address columns using numerical indices in this case, and subsequently use the `pd.DataFrame.astype` method to cast it to a categorical datatype:

```
df.iloc[:, -1] = df.iloc[:,-1].astype("category")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading from a csv or so, you can specify header to be None, and you can set the names of columns, if ofcourse you know it.

But, I feel this is not the case with you and anyways you've almost done it correctly, you don't need to take df again i.e.

`df.iloc[:,-1] = pd.Categorical(df.iloc[:,-1])`

This would suffice.